# Windows Authentication issue with C# MVC web site

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, http-status-code-403, iis-8

I am using Windows Authentication for the first time in a C# MVC web project and i have run into some issues.  If i am accessing the website from localhost, the browser will prompt for windows credentials.  This only happens with a new browser session.  After that the site is opened.
When i try to access the site from a remote machine on the same network the browser does not prompt for credentials and I receive a 403 error.  Viewing the page is declined.  I created a login page to redirect unauthorized users to.  Their credentials will be approved via Active Directory.  In order to do this i had to enable Anonymous Authentication in IIS which i thought shouldn't be done when using Windows Authentication instead of Forms.
Could some one please help me with the 403 error and best practices/configurations for Windows Authentication?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:
web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I did have to keep Anonymous Authentication enabled in IIS which i'm still not sure is correct.  Windows Authentication also enabled in IIS